# Script for auto Timestamp (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I need some help in making an auto updating timestamp script for my google spreadsheet. What I exactly need is that, when someone edits column A or B, a date and time will appear on column D.

I tried using this script

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 3);
//if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}

if( r.getColumn() == 5 ) { //checks the column
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
//if( nextCell.getValue() !== '' ) //is empty?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}

}
}
```

It worked fine for me, but when I share it, it won't work others. I have close to zero experience with codes/scripts, so can someone please help me?

Comment: Do the 'others' have editing rights in the column of the timestamp? Is that column a 'protected range'?